# Manage map zoom in LibGDX

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I manage the map through image views placed side by side to form a grid. How could I implement map zoom-in and zoom-out by loading all frames and elements without them getting distorted?

Comment: There are many ways to implement zooming on a tiled map and an answer depends on the method you are using to render.

Can you @CaP show us any of you rendering code as that will make it easier to provide a good answer?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any details about your rendering method I would suggest to use a Camera. The `OrthographicCamera` class provides a `zoom` attribute whereas the `PerspectiveCamera` can "zoom" via altering its `position.z`.